# wordpress theme my login action name?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I need to add action after login that counts the logins of users

My code so far is:

```
function count_logins($user_login, $wp_user) {

    $metaName = 'logins_count_since_release-0-0';

    $login_count = (int)get_user_meta($wp_user->ID, $metaName, true);
    $login_count++;

    update_user_meta($wp_user->ID, $metaName, $login_count);

    error_log('WAS HERE');

}

add_action('wp_login', 'count_logins', 10, 2);
```

I've tried wp_authenticate too instead of wp_login but this still doesn't work.

I've added this code inside my header.php file

The problem is, after I login with theme-my-login, and check my apache2 error.log, I don't have the line 'WAS HERE' so I guess this theme-my-login uses different action after login right?

What is the right action for this to work?

Thx.

**EDIT/Solved**

I moved this to wp-includes/user.php

since I have a custom made theme

```
function count_logins($username) {

    $user_id = username_exists($username);
    $metaName = 'logins_count_since_release-0-0';

    $login_count = (int)get_user_meta($user_id, $metaName, true);
    $login_count++;

    update_user_meta($user_id, $metaName, $login_count);

}

add_action('wp_authenticate', 'count_logins', 10, 1);
```

Comment: You can look in your database, too, to see if the meta value is stored.

Comment: Add this code to theme loading file, header.php is template file. your action is alreay done before header.php load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to theme loading/action-hook file, header.php is **template** file. your action is already done **before** header.php load.

WordPress Documentation

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate

Comment: so where exactly do i add this? to the wp-includes/users.php ? i would like to do this without changing wordpress is this possible? if not any option is ok

Comment: which theme you are using ? add in theme file not in wordpress core.